# Asset (js, css, images) loading is extremly slow on apache after update

Tags: apache-2.4, update, slow-connection

I am running an Ubuntu 14.04 based linux web server and did an update by "apt-get upgrade". Everything worked fine before this update. After this update the time to load assets like JS- or CSS-files is randomly extreme high examples:

[image]

[image]

I didn't change any configuration. I'm running three websites with Typo3, Wordpress, Magento and on every system I have the same problems. (you can try it yourself on *magento.byte-connect.de*)

I already deactivated mod_deflate, but it didn't change anything.

I actually have installed the following versions:

- Linux Ubuntu 14.04
- Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Does anybody have an idea what may be wrong here?